# How do I pipeline GUI program with separate logic program base?

Tags: c++

Hi to put things simple I want to create basic logical program with pure data. Then send it to another one which will analyse it and show it as GUI. Is it possible to do in Windows in C++? ( I would like to make it as system version independent as I can so it should work regardless if it is XP or 10, but I know it could be impossible so let's say I am most interested in 8.1 solution). If it is how you do it? By pipelines? By redirecting streams? By writing to a file?( I know writing to a file is rather bad idea, what about other ways?) Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: There's no "the one and only true way" to solve this, all alternatives will work. A common and (relatively) simple solution is to create a pair of pipes, and use `CreateProcess` to run the "logic program". Use the pipes to write to the other programs standard input, and read from its standard output, and parse the data you read into a format that can be used by the GUI application.

Comment: Will this work for the games though ? I mean I read that if you send a lot of data by std out -> std in can be slow.

Comment: Is the "engine" of the game already implemented as a text-only program, maybe by someone else? You just want to make it a little prettier by using a graphical user interface? The yes this will work just fine, depending on the complexity of the input/output of the program you invoke though. If it's your own game, and you just want to separate the logic into a separate module, then consider using a DLL instead.

Comment: File writing or TCP streaming are both pretty common. Is suggest familiarizing yourself with Qt.

Comment: Well I am trying to make my own game, and writing this all in just one executable is highly annoying.

Comment: Writing a game should not be annoying, it should be a fun and rewarding experience. If you find it annoying, then maybe you should start thinking a little more about the design, and less on the game mechanics? I just started reading [Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/), it might give you some hints on how to untangle your design? Most importantly though, ***don't give up!*** :)

Comment: Well creating games is fun...but WINAPI is not. I thought I could easily separate WinAPI to a program which would only take input from texture loader and logic layer and show it onto screen.

Comment: Oh, there are *many* libraries to simplify those things, some C and some C++. Many of these libraries are even geared toward game development. I recommend you look into [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) (for a C library) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) for a C++ library. There are of course many others as well. Some libraries also handles events like input, creating OpenGL contexts if you want to do OpenGL 3D programming, audio and maybe even networking.